# Why is my node static file server dropping requests?

Tags: http, node.js

I have a standard node.js static file server that I want to use to serve normal html, js, css, and jpg files in the same directory (ie- a typical HTML5 single page app).  I would expect that the node server can handle this properly.  What I see is different.

The `index.html` file is served, but then subsequent requests are dropped (ie- they never make it to the server).  In my chrome dev tools, I see things like this:

```
GET http://projectcoho.cloudfoundry.com/css/coho.css  http://projectcoho.cloudfoundry.com/:7
GET http://projectcoho.cloudfoundry.com/sencha-touch/sencha-touch-debug.js  http://projectcoho.cloudfoundry.com/:8
GET http://projectcoho.cloudfoundry.com/coho-debug.js  http://projectcoho.cloudfoundry.com/:8
```

But, these resources exist on the server and you can reach them if you enter their URL directly.  And for these requests, my callback in app.js is never invoked (I can tell this because `console.log` is never called for these files.

Here is the app.js file:

```
var path = ".";
var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;;

var file = new(static.Server) (path, {
  cache: 600
});

mime.define({
   'text/css': ['css'],
   'text/javascript': ['js'],
   'image/jpeg': ['jpg', 'jpeg']
});

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var filename = libpath.join(path, uri);

    console.log("URI: " + request.url + " , filename: " + filename);

    libpath.exists(filename, function (exists) {
        console.log("Serving " + filename);
        if (!exists) {
            console.log("Not found");
            response.writeHead(404, {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            });
            response.write("404 Not Found\n");
            response.end();
            return;
        }

        if (fs.statSync(filename).isDirectory()) {
            filename += '/index.html';
        }

        var type = mime.lookup(filename);
                file.serveFile(filename, 200, {'content-type' : type}, request, response);
    });
}).listen(port);
```

What am I missing here?

I am using node v0.6.15

Comment: Andrew -- what is the "port" value - ie is your server listening on the correct port?

Comment: Do filesystem permissions allow your server to open and read the file? What happens if the requested file is a directory but that directory does not contain the `index.html` file?

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald When running on CloudFoundry, the port number is provided by the framework, but when running on localhost, the port is 3000.  Behavior is the same in either case.

Comment: @sarnold This is a case that i have not implemented yet.  I'm pretty sure the server would barf, but I'm trying to fix the bigger problem first.

Comment: and what is "rewriting" the URLS supplied to the browser to route the requests to the correct port?  Is that "built in" to CloudFoundry itself?

Comment: I think showing the link to CloudFoundry is a red herring.  This happens when I run on localhost as well.  I included the pieces about cloudfoundry in case anyone wanted to navigate to the url and try it out themselves.

Comment: @MurrayMcDonald to answer your question, yes.  Cloud Foundry rewrites the urls to use the appropriate port.

Comment: OK -- so when you are running locally and listening on port 3000 aand you serve out "index.html", do the URLS in that file route requests back to port 3000 ie http:://localhost:3000/some_file_name.hmtl or are the URLS just in the for http://localhost/some_file_name.html -- in which case the request is geting routed to port 80 by default?

Comment: Good question!  I don't know.  How would I find out?  The css files are using link rel tags like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coho.css" type="text/css"> and the js files use style tags.

Comment: More importantly, if this is the case, then presumably all I need to do is to listen on both ports 3000 and 80?

Comment: Not working.  I notice that when I run on localhost.  All the jpg, js, and css requests are going through port 3000.  Listening on port 80 does nothing.

Comment: What is standard node.js static file server?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You should probably ask it in a new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the answer was that my `cache.manifest` file was incorrect.  The client application was looking for resources in a cache, but the didn't exist.  When I corrected the manifest, things started working.