# Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)

Tags: node.js, http, fileserver

Is there Node.js ready-to-use tool (installed with `npm`), that would help me expose folder content as file server over HTTP.

Example, if I have

```
D:\Folder\file.zip
D:\Folder\file2.html
D:\Folder\folder\file-in-folder.jpg
```

Then starting in `D:\Folder\` `node node-file-server.js`
I could access file via

```
http://hostname/file.zip
http://hostname/file2.html
http://hostname/folder/file-in-folder.jpg
```

[Why is my node static file server dropping requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024052/why-is-my-node-static-file-server-dropping-requests)
reference some mystical

> standard node.js static file server

If there's no such tool, what framework should I use?

Related:
[Basic static file server in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268033/basic-static-file-server-in-nodejs)

Comment: I wrote a module called Cachemere which lets you do this. It also automatically caches all your resources. Check it out: https://github.com/topcloud/cachemere

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server - lightweight static web server, zero configuration

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905426/what-is-a-faster-alternative-to-pythons-http-server-or-simplehttpserver

Comment: I know it's a late answer.  but if you want daemon http-server/static-files-server,  you may need https://github.com/AJLoveChina/hs3 ,  which supports running as background task.

Answer (score 1372, accepted):

A good ready-to-use tool option could be [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server):

```
npx http-server -o /path/to/static/content
```

Being a NPM package, can also installed

```
npm install http-server -g
http-server -o /path/to/static/content
```

Comment: This is awesome. I needed to specify an address bc for some reason the default 0.0.0.0 wasn't cooperating w my dev environment. `http-server -a localhost` got er dun.

Comment: i use `http-server -a localhost -p 80`

Comment: Yeah; it's slightly weird in that it doesn't automap localhost, but you can access from 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: http-server works well for me on Windows. Btw, http-server -o  opens my default browser with index page on http://127.0.0.1:8080/. Also there is a bunch of other useful parameters. For quick tests it's really the best tool.

Comment: It's worth checking [browser-sync](https://www.browsersync.io/) too, which can do more-or-less the same thing but with the added bonus of live-updating when files are modified.

Comment: `--cors` to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` along with the response headers (ie when serving a json file)

Comment: I found useful `live-server` for development it watches changes.

Comment: Very nice! But for me, I need extra fuction like Basic Authentication. It will be awesome

Comment: `npx http-server` - npx turns it into a one-liner that downloads the necessary files and runs it.

Comment: It just downloads the file for me.

Comment: try this if you haven't installed `http-server` globally: `npx http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 80` this way your server will be accessible by all the machines that share the same network as yours.

Comment: This is beautiful! Got my static website running with a single command instead of having to install some extra web server!

Comment: Is this also possible with https-server ?

Comment: You made my day

Answer (score 260):

If you do not want to use ready tool, you can use the code below, as demonstrated by me at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Node_server_without_framework:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './index.html';

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
        case '.png':
            contentType = 'image/png';
            break;      
        case '.jpg':
            contentType = 'image/jpg';
            break;
        case '.wav':
            contentType = 'audio/wav';
            break;
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

}).listen(8125);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125/');
```

**UPDATE**
If you need to access your server from external demand/file, you need to overcome the CORS, in your node.js file by writing the below, as I mentioned in a previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761481/simple-ajax-request-to-localhost-nodejs-server/28089807#28089807)

```
// Website you wish to allow to connect
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

// Request methods you wish to allow
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

**UPDATE**

As Adrian mentioned, in the comments, he wrote an ES6 code with full explanation [here](http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2016/08/24/Building-a-Node-js-static-file-server-files-over-HTTP-using-ES6/), I just re-posting his code below, in case the code gone from the original site for any reason:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.argv[2] || 9000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);

  // parse URL
  const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url);
  // extract URL path
  let pathname = `.${parsedUrl.pathname}`;
  // based on the URL path, extract the file extension. e.g. .js, .doc, ...
  const ext = path.parse(pathname).ext;
  // maps file extension to MIME typere
  const map = {
    '.ico': 'image/x-icon',
    '.html': 'text/html',
    '.js': 'text/javascript',
    '.json': 'application/json',
    '.css': 'text/css',
    '.png': 'image/png',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
    '.wav': 'audio/wav',
    '.mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
    '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
    '.pdf': 'application/pdf',
    '.doc': 'application/msword'
  };

  fs.exists(pathname, function (exist) {
    if(!exist) {
      // if the file is not found, return 404
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.end(`File ${pathname} not found!`);
      return;
    }

    // if is a directory search for index file matching the extension
    if (fs.statSync(pathname).isDirectory()) pathname += '/index' + ext;

    // read file from file system
    fs.readFile(pathname, function(err, data){
      if(err){
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.end(`Error getting the file: ${err}.`);
      } else {
        // if the file is found, set Content-type and send data
        res.setHeader('Content-type', map[ext] || 'text/plain' );
        res.end(data);
      }
    });
  });


}).listen(parseInt(port));

console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
```

Comment: Surely, `response.writeHead(200` should be `response.writeHead(404` ;)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you get 404 it still writes the content type as if it was whatever was requested, instead of text/html?

Comment: Would that code not allow going up the file tree by doing something like http://127.0.0.1/../../../etc/passwd ? I see no checks against that.

Comment: If anyone interested in the ES6+ version, I created a static file server that handles MIME types:

https://gist.github.com/amejiarosario/53afae82e18db30dadc9bc39035778e5

Comment: @Adrian, well done, thanks for your added value comment.

Comment: in your example you have:              response.end(content, 'utf-8');
, how it will send binary file if you set utf8 as encoding?

Comment: @Adrian  This code is very awesome, but I have found a way to get root access with it.  The solution is to limit the amount of leading periods on the filename to one so you can't do `../../etc/password` stuff.  https://gist.github.com/amejiarosario/53afae82e18db30dadc9bc39035778e5

Comment: `pathname = pathname.replace(/^(\.)+/, '.');`

Comment: awesome dude... simple and plain answer without third party API to read and send static contents to client.

Comment: Excellent quick server version! Thanks. I am using font-awesome and got some problems, 404, because the filepath include a query:
http://localhost:8484/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0
and the extension can't be recognized.
Can use this to fix it,
add:
 var url = require('url');
 
and replace the filePath with:
 
 var q = url.parse(request.url, true);
  
    var filePath = '.' + q.pathname;
 
to retrieve the pathname without the query.

Comment: Because `exists` is deprecated, you should use `fs.access` instead. @HasanAYousef

Comment: For simple development tasks, I've found your approach to be better than bringing in some 'out of the box' service. No added dependencies, ability to do unorthodox things (today, I needed to do routing, and servers don't usually do it).

Comment: gist with cors and fs.readFile:
https://gist.github.com/dirkk0/b33000011102c96efba3474de445b78f

Answer (score 90):

For people wanting a server runnable from within NodeJS script:

You can use [expressjs/serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#serve-files-with-vanilla-nodejs-http-server) which replaces `connect.static` (which is no longer available as of connect 3):

`myapp.js:`

```
var http = require('http');

var finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var serve = serveStatic("./");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var done = finalhandler(req, res);
  serve(req, res, done);
});

server.listen(8000);
```

and then from command line:

- `$ npm install finalhandler serve-static`
- `$ node myapp.js`

Comment: FYI This did not work for me. I installed filehandler using `npm install filehandler` and the package is listed in the `node_modules` directory. But when I run `myapp.js` node throws an error, saying `Error: cannot find module filehandler`. If I comment out the require ststment to load filehandler the app loads serve-static just fine, so it looks like there's something wrong with the filhandler package. Today is December 12, 2014, so maybe the package has changed since this answer was posted?

Comment: It's `final` handler not `file`

Comment: another advantage of this solution is, files aren't cached, so you don't need to restart a process when making changes in code.

Answer (score 80):

I know it's not Node, but I've used Python's SimpleHTTPServer:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]
```

It works well and comes with Python.

Comment: Python3 equivalent: `python -m http.server [port]` (the mentioned one is for Python2)

Comment: Python fails for me when it is about serving large files like OS images. Fedora 23

Comment: And on PHP: `php -S localhost:8000`

Comment: I use this to quickly serve content from a folder all the time.

Comment: NodeJs equivalent `npx http-server [-p 8000] [<dir>]`

Comment: I cannot download multiple files simultaneously with python server. Any work around for that?

Comment: Haha, that's Crazy! so many upvotes :D

Answer (score 57):

From npm@5.2.0, `npm` started installing a new binary alongside the usual npm called `npx`. So now, one liners to create static http server from current directory:

Using https://github.com/vercel/serve

```
npx serve
```

or using https://github.com/http-party/http-server

```
npx http-server
```

Comment: so cool ..........     :D

Answer (score 37):

[**connect**](https://npmjs.org/package/connect) could be what you're looking for.

Installed easily with:

```
npm install connect
```

Then the most basic static file server could be written as:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    directory = '/path/to/Folder';

connect()
    .use(connect.static(directory))
    .listen(80);

console.log('Listening on port 80.');
```

Comment: This does not work any longer as of connect 3 as it doesn't expose `connect.static`; see my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24575241/) for a replacement

Comment: I believe that it is still bundled with **express** by default, but indeed exists now in a separate `require`able module "serve-static".

Answer (score 33):

## One-line™ Proofs instead of promises

[image]

#### The first is `http-server`, *`hs`* - [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

```
npm i -g http-server   // install
hs C:\repos            // run with one line?? FTW!!
```

#### The second is `serve` by ZEIT.co - [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)

```
npm i -g serve         // install
serve C:\repos         // run with one line?? FTW!!
```

---

Following are available options, if this is what helps you decide.

```
C:\Users\Qwerty>http-server --help
usage: http-server [path] [options]

options:
  -p           Port to use [8080]
  -a           Address to use [0.0.0.0]
  -d           Show directory listings [true]
  -i           Display autoIndex [true]
  -g --gzip    Serve gzip files when possible [false]
  -e --ext     Default file extension if none supplied [none]
  -s --silent  Suppress log messages from output
  --cors[=headers]   Enable CORS via the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header
                     Optionally provide CORS headers list separated by commas
  -o [path]    Open browser window after starting the server
  -c           Cache time (max-age) in seconds [3600], e.g. -c10 for 10 seconds.
               To disable caching, use -c-1.
  -U --utc     Use UTC time format in log messages.

  -P --proxy   Fallback proxy if the request cannot be resolved. e.g.: http://someurl.com

  -S --ssl     Enable https.
  -C --cert    Path to ssl cert file (default: cert.pem).
  -K --key     Path to ssl key file (default: key.pem).

  -r --robots  Respond to /robots.txt [User-agent: *\nDisallow: /]
  -h --help    Print this list and exit.
```

```
C:\Users\Qwerty>serve --help

  Usage: serve.js [options] [command]

  Commands:

    help  Display help

  Options:

    -a, --auth      Serve behind basic auth
    -c, --cache     Time in milliseconds for caching files in the browser
    -n, --clipless  Don't copy address to clipboard (disabled by default)
    -C, --cors      Setup * CORS headers to allow requests from any origin (disabled by default)
    -h, --help      Output usage information
    -i, --ignore    Files and directories to ignore
    -o, --open      Open local address in browser (disabled by default)
    -p, --port   Port to listen on (defaults to 5000)
    -S, --silent    Don't log anything to the console
    -s, --single    Serve single page applications (sets `-c` to 1 day)
    -t, --treeless  Don't display statics tree (disabled by default)
    -u, --unzipped  Disable GZIP compression
    -v, --version   Output the version number
```

---

If you need to watch for changes, see [`hostr`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostr), credit [Henry Tseng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http/30312255#30312255)

Answer (score 32):

Install express using npm: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Create a file named server.js at the same level of your index.html with this content:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
server.use(express.static(__dirname));
server.listen(8080);
```

This will load your index.html file. If you wish to specify the html file to load, use this syntax:

```
server.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/myfile.html'));
```

If you wish to put it in a different location, set the path on the third line:

```
server.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

CD to the folder containing your file and run node from the console with this command:

```
node server.js
```

Browse to localhost:8080

Comment: Hi, I can run it correctly, but it shows `Cannot GET /`. I use AWS EC2 to run the server.

Comment: @Wei Hi, late answer. From what I can see from a quick Google search it looks like your directory structure might be wrong. There must be an index.html file in the location you are targeting. Setting up the above example to run should take 5 minutes and I double checked that it works as is. From there you can tweak the path to suit your directory structure and check that the server still finds the files it needs to server.

Comment: `path.join(__dirname, 'public')` is more cross-platform.

Answer (score 19):

#DEMO/PROTO SERVER ONLY

If that's all you need, try this:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      http = require('http'),
      arg = process.argv.slice(2),
      rootdir = arg[0] || process.cwd(),
      port = process.env.PORT || 9000,
      hostname = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1';
//tested on node=v10.19.0
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  try {
    // change 'path///to/////dir' -> 'path/to/dir'
    req_url = decodeURIComponent(req.url).replace(/\/+/g, '/');

    stats = fs.statSync(rootdir + req_url);

    if (stats.isFile()) {
      buffer = fs.createReadStream(rootdir + req_url);
      buffer.on('open', () => buffer.pipe(res));
      return;
    }

    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      //Get list of files and folder in requested directory
      lsof = fs.readdirSync(rootdir + req_url, {encoding:'utf8', withFileTypes:false});
      // make an html page with the list of files and send to browser
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
      res.end(html_page(`http://${hostname}:${port}`, req_url, lsof));
      return;
    }

  } catch (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(err);
      return;
  }
}).listen(port, hostname, () => console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}`));


function html_page(host, req_url, lsof) {//this is a Function declarations can be called before it is defined
  // Add link to root directory and parent directory if not already in root directory
  list = req_url == '/' ? [] : [`<a href="${host}">/</a>`,
  `<a href="${host}${encodeURI(req_url.slice(0,req_url.lastIndexOf('/')))}">..</a>`];

  templete = (host, req_url, file) => {// the above is a Function expressions cannot be called before it is defined
    return `<a href="${host}${encodeURI(req_url)}${req_url.slice(-1) == '/' ? '' : '/'}${encodeURI(file)}">${file}</a>`; }

  // Add all the links to the files and folder in requested directory
  lsof.forEach(file => {
    list.push(templete(host, req_url, file));
  });

  return `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Directory of ${req_url}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Directory of ${req_url}</h2>
${list.join('<br/>\n')}
</body>
</html>`
}
```

Comment: Don't use the sync version. Instread create pipe to res from readStream.

Comment: Best answer if you need a quick & dirty one-time one trick pony.

Comment: If you want to avoid using `index.html` as part of your address just add `if (req.url === '/') req.url = '/index.html';` right after `res.writeHead(200);`.

Comment: @EduardBondarenko is right. `const stream = fs.createReadStream(...); stream.pipe(res);` is all you need

Answer (score 13):

In plain node.js:

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

process.on('uncaughtException', err => console.error('uncaughtException', err))
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => console.error('unhandledRejection', err))

const publicFolder = process.argv.length > 2 ? process.argv[2] : '.'
const port = process.argv.length > 3 ? process.argv[3] : 8080

const mediaTypes = {
  zip: 'application/zip',
  jpg: 'image/jpeg',
  html: 'text/html',
  /* add more media types */
}

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.method + ' ' + request.url)

  const filepath = path.join(publicFolder, request.url)
  fs.readFile(filepath, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      response.statusCode = 404
      return response.end('File not found or you made an invalid request.')
    }

    let mediaType = 'text/html'
    const ext = path.extname(filepath)
    if (ext.length > 0 && mediaTypes.hasOwnProperty(ext.slice(1))) {
      mediaType = mediaTypes[ext.slice(1)]
    }

    response.setHeader('Content-Type', mediaType)
    response.end(data)
  })
})

server.on('clientError', function onClientError(err, socket) {
  console.log('clientError', err)
  socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n')
})

server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1', function() {
  console.log('‍ Development server is online.')
})
```

**This is a simple node.js server that only serves requested files in a certain directory.**

Usage:

```sh
node server.js folder port
```

`folder` may be absolute or relative depending on the `server.js` location. The default value is `.` which is the directory you execute `node server.js` command.

`port` is 8080 by default but you can specify any port available in your OS.

In your case, I would do:

```sh
cd D:\Folder
node server.js
```

You can browse the files under `D:\Folder` from a browser by typing `http://127.0.0.1:8080/somefolder/somefile.html`

Answer (score 9):

There is another static web server that is quite nice: browser-sync.

It can be downloaded using node package manager:

```
npm install -g browser-sync
```

After installation, navigate to the project folder in the cmd prompt and just run the following:

```
browser-sync start --server --port 3001 --files="./*"
```

It will start catering all the files in the current folder in the browser.

More can be found out from [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/)

Thanks.

Comment: The advantage of using Browsersync rather than other static servers is that it live updates the page whenever the files specified by the `--files` flag change (nb. you don't need to specify `./*` - only the ones that you want Browsersync to actively watch for updates, eg. `css/*.css`)

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://pad.js.org) is my one-file/lightweight node.js static file web-server pet project with no-dependency that I believe is a quick and rich tool which its use is as easy as issuing this command on your Linux/Unix/macOS terminal (or [termux](https://termux.com) on Android) when node.js (or `nodejs-legacy` on Debian/Ubuntu) is installed:

```
curl pad.js.org | node
```

(different commands exist for Windows users on the documentation)

It supports different things that I believe can be found useful,

- Hierarchical directory index creation/serving

  - With sort capability on the different criteria
  - Upload from browser by [multi-file] drag-and-drop and file/text-only copy-paste and system clipboard screen-shot paste on Chrome, Firefox and other browsers may with some limitations (which can be turned off by command line options it provides)
  - Folder/note-creation/upload button
- Serving correct MIMEs for well known file types (with possibility for disabling that)
- Possibility of installation as a npm package and local tool or, one-linear installation as a permanent service with Docker
- HTTP 206 file serving (multipart file transfer) for faster transfers
- Uploads from terminal and browser console (in fact it was originally intended to be a file-system proxy for JS console of browsers on other pages/domains)
- CORS download/uploads (which also can be turned off)
- Easy HTTPS integration
- Lightweight command line options for achieving better secure serving with it:

  - With my patch on [node.js 8](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/13012), you can have access to the options without first installation: `curl pad.js.org | node - -h`
  - Or first install it as a system-global npm package by `[sudo] npm install -g pad.js` and then use its installed version to have access to its options: `pad -h`
  - Or use the provided Docker image which uses relatively secure options by default. `[sudo] docker run --restart=always -v /files:/files --name pad.js -d -p 9090:9090 quay.io/ebraminio/pad.js`

[image: Screenshot of a folder index using the tool]

The features described above are mostly documented on the main page of the tool http://pad.js.org which by some nice trick I used is also the place the tool source itself is also served from!

The tool source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ebraminio/pad.js) which welcomes your feedback, feature requests and ⭐s!

Answer (score 8):

You can use the NPM [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) package for this, if you don't need the NodeJS stuff it is a quick and easy to use tool:

1 - Install the package on your PC:

```
npm install -g serve
```

2 - Serve your static folder with `serve <path>` :

```
d:> serve d:\StaticSite
```

It will show you which port your static folder is being served, just navigate to the host like:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Comment: You realize that `npm` is the node package manager so you're in fact using the NodeJS stuff

Comment: I do, What I meant as "NodeJS stuff" was using NodeJS and express to serve the files like most answers suggested. Serve is an independent executable, NPM is used just to install it, you could just download it directly.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't had much luck with any of the answers on this page, however, below seemed to do the trick.

Add a `server.js` file with the following content:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const app = express()

// serve static assets normally
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))

// handle every other route with index.html, which will contain
// a script tag to your application's JavaScript file(s).
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port)
console.log("server started on port " + port)
```

Also make sure that you require `express`. Run `yarn add express --save` or `npm install express --save` depending on your setup (I can recommend `yarn` it's pretty fast).

You may change `dist` to whatever folder you are serving your content is. For my simple project, I wasn't serving from any folder, so I simply removed the `dist` filename.

Then you may run `node server.js`. As I had to upload my project to a Heroku server, I needed to add the following to my `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Below worked for me:

Create a file `app.js` with below contents:

```
// app.js

var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + req.url, function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
      return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Create a file `index.html` with below contents:

```
Hi
```

Start a command line:

```
cmd
```

Run below in `cmd`:

```
node app.js
```

Goto below URL, in chrome:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html
```

That's all. Hope that helps.

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/), this functionality comes ready to go.

To setup a simple file serving app just do this:

```
mkdir yourapp
cd yourapp
npm install express
node_modules/express/bin/express
```

Comment: Can I $ npm install -g express ; them $ express ?

Comment: I followed your steps, but my express does not have _bin_ folder

Answer (score 4):

Searching in NPM registry https://npmjs.org/search?q=server, I have found static-server https://github.com/maelstrom/static-server

> Ever needed to send a colleague a file, but can't be bothered emailing
>   the 100MB beast? Wanted to run a simple example JavaScript
>   application, but had problems with running it through the file:///
>   protocol? Wanted to share your media directory at a LAN without
>   setting up Samba, or FTP, or anything else requiring you to edit
>   configuration files? Then this file server will make your life that
>   little bit easier.
>
> To install the simple static stuff server, use npm:
>
> ```
> npm install -g static-server
> ```
>
> Then to serve a file or a directory, simply run
>
> ```
> $ serve path/to/stuff
> Serving path/to/stuff on port 8001
> ```

That could even list folder content.

Unfortunately, [it couldn't serve files](https://github.com/maelstrom/static-server/issues/1) :)

Comment: I built that server. That file server was built against a *very* old version of Node, hence why it does not work any more. I do not have the time right now to fix it up. I suggest using the answer by @Oleg above. It can be easily bundled into a small node executable, and is essentially what mine did anyway.

Comment: Thank you Tim, very professional response. I wouldn't delete code though, but update readme.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [serve-me](https://www.npmjs.org/package/serve-me)

Using it is so easy:

```
ServeMe = require('serve-me')();
ServeMe.start(3000);
```

Thats all.

PD: The folder served by default is "public".

Answer (score 4):

Here's another simple web server.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hostr

Install

```
npm install -g hostr
```

Change working director

```
cd myprojectfolder/
```

And start

```
hostr
```

Comment: This also watches for changes and provides live reload.

Answer (score 4):

For a healthy increase of performance using node to serve static resources, I recommend using [Buffet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffet). It works similar to as a web application accelerator also known as a caching HTTP reverse proxy but it just loads the chosen directory into memory.

> Buffet takes a fully-bufferred approach -- all files are fully loaded into memory when your app boots, so you will never feel the burn of the filesystem. In practice, this is immensely efficient. So much so that putting Varnish in front of your app might even make it slower!

We use it on the codePile site and found an increase of ~700requests/sec to >4k requests/sec on a page that downloads 25 resources under a 1k concurrent user connection load.

Example:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();

var buffet = require('buffet')(root: './file'); 

 

server.on('request', function (req, res) {

  buffet(req, res, function () {

    buffet.notFound(req, res);

  });

});

 

server.listen(3000, function () {

  console.log('test server running on port 3000');

});
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on that [link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

You need only to install express module of `node js`.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/Folder', express.static(__dirname + '/Folder'));
```

You can access your file like http://hostname/Folder/file.zip

Answer (score 3):

First install node-static server via `npm install node-static -g`  -g is to install it global on your system, then  navigate to the directory where your files are located, start the server with `static`   it listens on port 8080, naviaget to the browser and type localhost:8080/yourhtmlfilename.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Static-Server using connect

```
var connect = require('connect'),
  directory = __dirname,
  port = 3000;

connect()
  .use(connect.logger('dev'))
  .use(connect.static(directory))
  .listen(port);

console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
```

See also [Using node.js as a simple web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/node-js-as-a-simple-web-server)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't on NPM, yet, but I built a simple static server on Express that also allows you to accept form submissions and email them through a transactional email service (Sendgrid for now, Mandrill coming).

https://github.com/jdr0dn3y/nodejs-StatServe

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of searchers, I liked Jakub g's answer, but wanted a little error handling. Obviously it's best to handle errors [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313005/852806), but this should help prevent a site stopping if an error occurs. Code below:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});

var server = express();

server.use(express.static(__dirname));

var port = 10001;
server.listen(port, function() { 
    console.log('listening on port ' + port);     
    //var err = new Error('This error won't break the application...')
    //throw err
});
```

Comment: Update - My answer works, but I now use @Matt Self's answer of using http-server. It seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

For dev work you can use (express 4)
https://github.com/appsmatics/simple-httpserver.git

Answer (score 1):

If you want daemon http-server/static-files-server,  you may need https://github.com/AJLoveChina/hs3 ,  which supports running as background task.

```
npm install -g hs3
```

Usage

move to the directory which serve static files and run

```
hs3
```

**Really fast and quick? Yes !** And the file server or static server will be running as background task.

It also supports using another http port, or https. Please click https://github.com/AJLoveChina/hs3 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I use Houston at work and for personal projects, it works well for me.

https://github.com/alejandro/Houston

Answer (score 0):

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');


let mimeTypes = {
  '.html': 'text/html',
  '.css': 'text/css',
  '.js': 'text/javascript',
  '.jpg': 'image/jpeg',
  '.png': 'image/png',
  '.ico': 'image/x-icon',
  '.svg': 'image/svg+xml',
  '.eot': 'appliaction/vnd.ms-fontobject',
  '.ttf': 'aplication/font-sfnt'
};



http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  let pathName = url.parse(request.url).path;
  if(pathName === '/'){
    pathName = '/index.html';
  }
  pathName = pathName.substring(1, pathName.length);
  let extName = path.extName(pathName);
  let staticFiles = `${__dirname}/template/${pathName}`;

      if(extName =='.jpg' || extName == '.png' || extName == '.ico' || extName == '.eot' || extName == '.ttf' || extName == '.svg')
      {
          let file = fr.readFileSync(staticFiles);
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeTypes[extname]});
          res.write(file, 'binary');
          res.end();
      }else {
        fs.readFile(staticFiles, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          if(!err){
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': mimeTypes[extname]});
            res.end(data);
          }else {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf8'});
            res.write(`<strong>${staticFiles}</strong>File is not found.`);
          }
          res.end();
        });
      }
}).listen(8081);
```

Comment: You should add some explanation alog with this code.

Comment: Lot's of error in this. Variable names are not consistend (response, res etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you are intrested in ultra-light http server without any prerequisites
you should have a look at: [mongoose](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mongoose/)

Comment: This is a C++ Server which has no relation to a Node.js Solution. Also the name is misleading in this Thread because it shares it's name with a popular MongoDB Layer for Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You also asked why requests are dropping - not sure what's the specific reason on your case, but in overall you better server static content using dedicated middleware (nginx, S3, CDN) because Node is really not optimized for this networking pattern. See further explanation here (bullet 13):
http://goldbergyoni.com/checklist-best-practice-of-node-js-in-production/

Answer (score 0):

small command-line web server on Node.js: [miptleha-http](https://github.com/miptleha/miptleha-http)

full source [code](https://github.com/miptleha/miptleha-http/blob/master/miptleha-http.js) (80 lines)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install npm packages

> npm install forever http-server

2. forever start $(which http-server) -p 8000 -d false [FILE_DIRECTORY]

> forever start /usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
> -p 8000 /home/web-files/

3. Altenatively,

> http-server -p 8000 /home/web-files/