# Node.js - Content-Type for html file which has javascript file too?

Tags: node.js, http

What should be the Content-Type in writeHead method of response object?

text/plain or application/javascript ?

index.html has index.js too and Node.js http server will send both file to the client(.html as well as .js).

I am getting following error in chrome

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: `"http://localhost:8111/index.js"`

**Node.js**

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(function(request,response){
                fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function(error,data){
                                response.writeHead(200);
                                response.end(data);
                });
                });

httpServer.listen(8111);
```

**index.html has:**

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where do you serve the js file ? You send the html file in answer to all requests ?

Comment: Do I need to send it separately with another response.send()?

Comment: You have to send it separately in answer to a different request. Which means you must look at what's the request.

Comment: Your server is returning always the index.html content with the by default MIME text/html, maybe you should consider to use connect or expressjs frameworks, depending on what you need. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16333915/661140

Comment: but same index.html has <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script> which is successfully served by the same script

Comment: You could also use something like the `node-static` module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-static) if you're just serving static files.

Comment: To complete what's said by @RobertoSánchez, serving the files of a directory using express is done as easily as [`app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));`](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/main.js#L111).

Comment: That's because that script is served by Cloudflare, not your server, their adding the correct content-type.

Comment: okay got it. Implementing it by native node.js is a big pain I guess. let me check express or connect. Thanks

Comment: @PK no, it's not a *big* pain, you just have to write a few lines to deal with paths, mime types and such things. It's just easier to reuse what's available in many libraries like express.

Comment: got it. I will try to implement it, actually once we have a number of css,script and image files it would be little bit difficult. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Include the object specifying the content type of your `index.html` file just like below.

```
response.writeHead(200);
```

becomes

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```