# How to display image inside HTML document using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm displaying some text that i've created inside HTML file using node.js (by method createServer).

Everything was working fine until i added picture inside the document, which doesn't get display on the site.

**This is my code**

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});


//read HTML
fs.readFile(__dirname + '//funkcionalnosti.html', function (err, data) {    
    console.log(data.toString());
    res.end(data);
});
```

**This is my code for image inside HTML file**
[image]

**And this is where picture is located**

Picture as located same as HTML file, so i dont any **../** are necessary in order for it ti work. I've also tried adding the ful path and subdirectories but the picture won't show.

[image]

**I've also tried this that i found on stackoverflow, but it's still not working**

```
var image_origial = "diagram.jpg";
fs.readFile(image_origial, function (err, original_data) {
    fs.writeFile('diagram.jpg', original_data, function (err) { });
    var base64Image = original_data.toString('base64');
    var decodedImage = new Buffer(base64Image, 'base64');
    fs.writeFile('diagram.jpg', decodedImage, function (err) { });
});
```

**Also tried this**

```
res.write('<img src="data:diagram.jpg/;base64,imagedata">');
```

**Or this**

```
res.write('<img src="data:diagram.jpg/jpg;base64,imagedata">');
```

But no luck so far, please help me out, im desperate

**Any help will be appreciated!!!**

**How is this a duplicate to "bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this. You haven't handled route for the image that you are trying to access.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request starting...');

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './index.html';

    var extname = path.extname(filePath);
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    switch (extname) {
        case '.js':
            contentType = 'text/javascript';
            break;
        case '.css':
            contentType = 'text/css';
            break;
        case '.json':
            contentType = 'application/json';
            break;
        case '.png':
            contentType = 'image/png';
            break;      
        case '.jpg':
            contentType = 'image/jpg';
            break;
        case '.wav':
            contentType = 'audio/wav';
            break;
    }

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end(); 
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

}).listen(8125);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8125/');
```

Original Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869/2861108

Comment: where do i address my .html file? it's kinda confusing this code

Comment: @fox Please use express framework. try googleing express.static

Comment: @NidhinDavid i would love to, but this is assignment for uni and we are not allowed to, not yet...

Comment: @fox You just need to place this code in an `index.js` file in same directory which you want to be root directory of your server.

Comment: @fox Try the above answer. It must solve your issue. The issue is that there is no route or handler for the images route. Without using frameworks you must add your own route/handlers

Comment: @MjZac yeh i did, but it wasn't working, but then i saw the port was different to mine, so i changed it. thank you very much it works now!!!

Comment: @NidhinDavid thanks man, hope we can start using express asap :)