# Chrome complaining about html tags in app.js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, http, single-page-application

I am trying to make a simple SPA with angular and node. When I try to test if my SPA is working in chrome, chrome gives me a peculiar error. It is complaining about html tags in my demoApp.js, even though it does not contain any HTML code. How can this be?

Error: demoApp.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

test.html

```
<html ng-app="demoApp">
  <head>
        <title>My Angular App</title>

  </head>

  <body>
      <h2>DemoApp Demo</h2>
        <div>
            <a href="#/partial1.html">Partial 1</a>
            <a href="#/partial2.html">Partial 2</a>
            <div ng-view></div>     
        </div>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src = "demoApp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

demoApp.js

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

demoApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when('/',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/partial1.html'
        }).when('/partial2',
        {
            controller: 'SimpleController',
            templateUrl: 'Partials/partial2.html'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);


demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
    $scope.customers = [
        {name:'Victor', city:'Norrköping'}, 
        {name:'Mikael', city:'Göteborg'}, 
        {name:'Jocke',  city:'Göteborg'}, 
        {name:'Skåne',  city:'Ystad'}
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
        $scope.customers.push(
        {
            name: $scope.newCustomer.name, 
            city: $scope.newCustomer.city
        });
    }
});
```

server.js

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    fs.readFile('./test.html', null, function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Comment: you sending test.html  when browser request app js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are serving only your index.html no matter you request to your server.

You need to change your server.js to something like this:

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    var path;
    if (request.url === '/') {
        path = './test.html';
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    } else {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
        path = '.' + request.url;
    }
    fs.readFile(path, null, function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write('File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

**Note:** this is a very bad static server, it just returns everything as a javascript. You should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http) and create a better static server, or just use nginx