# Send PHP file with NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js

I would like to send a PHP file with NodeJS instead of HTML file,
This is my script:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/serv.html'));
})
```

It doesn't works when I replace 'serv.html' with 'serv.php'...

Thank you very much

Comment: Why would you need that ?

Comment: Because I need my clients to use PHP.

Comment: Maybe it could help you ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824678/cant-process-php-files-with-node-js

Comment: It doesn't works for me