# Dojo themePreviewer stuck "Loading..."

Tags: javascript, dojo

I downloaded the latest Dojo and Dijit to my local Windows 10 computer.

My disk structure is:

```
C:\webapps 
c:\webapps\dojo 
c:\webapps\demo 
c:\webapps\dijit
```

I'm clicking on this file to load with Chrome browser: 
c:\webapps\demos\themePreviewer\demo.html

It shows the following, and is stuck forever with the "Loading..." message.

[image]

Internally, I see the following references to css files:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dijit/themes/claro/document.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
```

I can see those on my disk, here:

```
c:\webapps\dijit\themes\claro\document.css 
c:\webapps\dijit\themes\claro\claro.css
```

Seems like it's a problem finding the files? But wouldn't Chrome debug tell me that? I also tried copying the dijit directory to:

c:\webapps\demo\dijit

Later I noticed there is one href in the program: 
href:'../../dijit/tests/layout/getResponse.php?delay=3000&messId=3'

that I changed to:
href:'http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/tests/layout/getResponse.php?delay=3000&messId=3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the app from a localhost instead of file:///.
In case the problem persist, you could debug it more and see if some dependencies are missing using Chrome Developer Tools > Network tab, in this way you should be able to identify any 404 errors.

Comment: This can be the issue. I have faced this many times. Usually, there is a warning in Chrome's console regarding this also. It's always best to load this via a server. I use [XAMPP Server](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) for this.

Comment: Yes definitely any server would do the job :) Please let me know how you were able to solve your issue.

Comment: PS: If you found my answer useful, please do not forget to upvote/accept it. Thanks for it :).

Comment: I used nodeJS http-server and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http.  But why?  Why wouldn't file system work equally well?

Comment: @NealWalters It could be related to a configuration issue on XAMPP Server. Thanks for accepting my answer :)