# Dojo and NodeJS (Express/Routing)

Tags: node.js, dojo

I'm now taking this to the next level: 
[Dojo themePreviewer stuck "Loading..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357028/dojo-themepreviewer-stuck-loading)

I want to build a node.js application that will implement a lot of JSON routines, and also serve the Dojo/Diji/css files.

I tried this (where /student is my JSON):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/apps', express.static(__dirname + '/apps'));
app.use('/dojo', express.static(__dirname + '/dojo'));
app.use('/dijit', express.static(__dirname + '/dijit'));
app.get('/student', function(request, response){ ... etc... }
```

From the browser, I loaded: http://localhost:3000/apps/dojoThemeTester.html
and the ThemeTester comes up and looks perfect.

[image]

But when I click on anything on it, such as a calendar date, or a tab, absolutely nothing happens.

Once that is working, my goal is to make a copy of dojoThemeTester.html, customize it, then use Ajax to call the JSON webservices in the same NodeJS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, but I went back to the original files and compared, and for some reason, the file I was loading in the browser was very different from the one that worked before.  I thought they were the same.

I also used Chrome F12 to find some missing files: 
[image]