# Error when loading .json/.csv in

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to learn D3 with this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2S1AbEWX85o), but I got stuck when I try to load an external file. The codes are as below:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <body>

    <script>
    d3.json("mydata.json", function(data){

      var canvas=d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
          .attr("width", 500)
          .attr("height", 500);

      canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
          .attr("width", function(d){return d.age*10;})
          .attr("height", 50)
          .attr("fill", "blue")
          .attr("y", function(d,i){return i * 60});

      canvas.select("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
          .attr("fill", "white")
          .attr("y", function(d, i){return i * 60})
          .text(function(d) {return d.name;});
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**mydata.json**

```
[
  {"name": "Maria", "age": 30},
  {"name": "Fred", "age": 50},
  {"name": "Francis", "age": 12}
]
```

And I try to run it in a server:

**app.js**

```
const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');

const hostname='127.0.0.1';
const port=3000;

fs.readFile('index.html', (err, html) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  const server =http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode =200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
    res.write(html);
    res.end();
  });

  server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port '+port);
  });
});
```

I keep getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: canvas.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a
>   function

When I try to use version 3 of D3, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

When I try to load a .csv file instead, I get the following error:

> Error:  attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the way you set up your server. No matter what you requested from it, it will always respond by sending the contents of `index.html`. This equally holds true if you request `mydata.json` which will also yield `index.html`'s contents.

Because that file does not contain valid JSON, it cannot be parsed by `d3.json()` causing the callback's `data` parameter to be `null`. When passing `null` to `.enter()` it will act as a [getter](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data), which—at least in your case—yields an empty array:

> If data is not specified, this method returns the array of data for the selected elements.

Obviously, this array does not feature a `.enter()` method, hence the error.

```js
var data = d3.selectAll("div")
  .data(null);

console.log(data);          // []: Empty array
console.log(data.enter());  // "Uncaught TypeError: data.enter is not a function"
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

The solution to this is to correctly set up your server to return the contents your are after.

---

Furthermore, to harden your code, you might want to check for errors occurring during loading or parsing, which will be handed over to the [callback](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#json) passed to `d3.json()`:

> The callback is invoked with two arguments: the error, if any, and the
>   response value. The response value is undefined if an error occurs.

Although not mandatory, this will make debugging much easier.

```
d3.json("mydata.json",function(error, data) {
  // Handle error (logging, throwing, whatever)
  if (error) throw error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, May I ask if there is  any way for a quick fix of the server?

Comment: @nganlong There are numerous options to address this issue. If you want to stick to your programmatic approach you might want to have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869/4235784) to [*“ Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP“*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http/16350826). Otherwise, you could just use a simple out-of-the-box HTTP server as proposed by the accepted answer to that question.