# Node.js: JustGage is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, justgage

I am trying to write a simple node.js based application which can use JustGage (JavaScript-based plugin). Following is my Node.js application.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Following is the index.html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Temperature Sensor</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/resources/js/justgage.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="static/resources/js/raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    window.onload = function(){
      var g = new JustGage({
        id: "g_a411_faculty",
          value: 22, 
          min: 10,
          max: 40,
          title: "A411 - Faculty Office",
          label: "Celsius",
          levelColors: [
            "#ffffff",
            "#f9c802",
            "#FF0000"
          ]
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="g_a411_faculty" class="col-sm-6" style="width:400px; height:320px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code and open http://localhost:8080 in Google Chrome, the index page shows an error that JustGage is not defined (in Developer tools). However, when I simply open up index.html (without using Node.js) in Chrome, the page works fine. Can you please help where am I going wrong?

I tried to resolve the issue by installing justgage package by

```
npm install justgage
```

However, when I write

```
var jg = require('justgage');
```

This shows a Reference Error - the document is not defined. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

node.js isn't serving your static folder.

The website works when running directly from the folder as you are able to access the relative path of `static/...` from the same location.

When you run via node.js, you are only serving index.html and not the related assets.

Some useful ways of serving static files/folders are discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http) thread

Comment: That was spot on! I created an http-server to host the remaining files and then used that link in the src option.