# Style and javascript files not applied to page that is serving HTML in Node.js

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, server, readfile

I am currently serving my HTML page which references style.css and index.js, however, these files are not being applied to the HTML page even though I explicitly stated to include them if they are requested by 'req'?

My HTML (to show inclusions):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Test site</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" media="screen">

      <script src="/index.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>

      .
      .
      .
```

My server.js code:

```
var PORT = 3000;
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

//cache the files
var index = fs.readFileSync('public/index.html', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});
var style = fs.readFileSync('public/style.css', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});
var indexJS = fs.readFileSync('public/index.js', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
});

function requestHandler(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.write(index);
    if(req.url === '/style.css'){
        res.write(style);
    }
    if(req.url === '/index.js'){
        res.write(indexJS);
    }
    res.end();
}

//use 3000 by default if PORT is not defined
if(!(typeof PORT !== 'undefined') || PORT === null){
    http.createServer(requestHandler).listen(PORT);
}
else{
    http.createServer(requestHandler).listen(3000);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have the right idea but there are a couple things to note in the server code.

Setting the `Content Type` header tells the web browser how to interpret the file it is receiving. Your server code always sets it to 'text/html' where it should be set to 'text/css' for css, and 'text/javascript' for your js files.

`res.write` will append the file contents to the response. Since `res.write(index)` is being executed on every request, your HTML is being sent before the css/js within the same file. Try using a conditional for HTML like you are doing for CSS/JS like

```
if(req.url === '/') {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.write(index);
}
```

Comment: Ah okay, makes sense. Thanks so much for helping me understand this!