# MIME type error for local CSS or JS prevents loading custom styles when working with NodeJs

Tags: css, node.js, styles, mime-types, mime

I am racking my brain the whole week on this error now!
My plan was to create a simple **'send email from nodejs' application**. The problem that I ran into was, a **mime-type error** for my **style.css**. The error says it's is in a **text/html** format.
I started as usual with 'npm init -y' and 'npm install express nodemailer nodemailer-mailgun-transport -S'.
I also created a 'server.js', 'index.html' and 'style.css' (See code below).
And that's it. The application works as expected and linking bootstrap cdn also works. It is only my custom css that gives me a hard time. So to simplify it I even took a copy/paste html template from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_css_internal)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body> 
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
p {
  color: red;
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
})

app.listen(PORT);
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "SendMail",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.15",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "style": "style.css"
}
```

The error in Chrome:
[image: Error in chrome]

What I've tried:

- Isolating the html/css part to make sure the code is alright. Yes, it is!
- experimenting around with the style link. Including this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45119502/12272930
- Change the mime-type via javascript like: [Style and javascript files not applied to page that is serving HTML in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50429529/12272930)
- Attaching a style section in package.json as shown above

Edit: Inline styling and JS works as expected. I am guessing that it has something to do with express.

Is there anything else that I could try?
Let me know if you need additional info. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When serving static files (like images, css, etc.) it is usually best practice to place those files in a dedicated directory called public or static, or whatever you like. Then you need explicitly tell your express app to serve files from there like so:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

So your server.js becomes:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
})

app.listen(PORT);
```

And then you can call your CSS file like this in your index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body> 
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, and remove   "style": "style.css" from your package.json.

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately the error is still remaining. I followed your instructions and double checked everything. Did you manage to get the code working with this correction?

Comment: I also tried adding path.join() for combining __dirname and '/public'

Comment: Yea, it worked for me. Did you try it in a different browser? I tested this in Mac and Safari and it was OK

Comment: Yes. I tried Firefox and Chrome.
Ok. So I managed to get the stylesheet working by starting the server via the vscode express plugin. All other functionalities do not work. So I need to start it with the command 'node server.js' to get it working properly. Do you know what could be the diefference here?

Comment: I tested it by running node server.js as well. Not sure why it would behave differently, but I would imagine it could be related to versioning/runtimes or something along those lines.

Comment: Ok I got it. Your solutions is correct. I moved the stylesheet into the public folder. But the problem was, that I added "public" to the stylesheet link in the html file. Since it is linkt via the script it shouldn't be linked manually anymore.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Good evening) Just make your folder with html/css is public.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'index.html'));
})

app.listen(PORT);
```