# Is there a way to host HTML website themes/templates (Themeforest, etc) on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, themes

I was just wondering if there's a way to implement Node.JS and its main file as a sort of container for a fully implemented HTML template/theme like those on Themeforest.

I looked around and saw JSDOM but I don't think that will fit my needs.

In case it isn't clear, Themeforest hosts HTML5 themes that are fully functioning HTML/CSS/JS files that you can just upload to your host file server and it will serve up your front end. I'm just getting tired of making React-styled apps, and just want to try these nice looking themes for a change.

Comment: Those themes still require you to adapt them to your use case and content. Download one and play with it

Answer (score 0):

As you are looking to host static HTML/CSS/JS contents, you just have to [run a basic server, as described by answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http). If you are looking for a production appropriate solution, you should also consider cloud storage/CDNs.