# Http server for node to list all files in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm pretty new to Node so I apologize if this is a simple question. But I'm trying to read the contents of a directory, `./resources`, then display links to them on the webpage. The catch is that the files in the directory are dynamic, so I'm using `fs.readdir` in Node.

But the `<h1>` is not showing on the `index.html` page; any ideas why?

```
const resDir = "resources/";
const resDirFiles = [];

const app = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  ...

  fs.readFile(filePath, (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      // To be implemented
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-type": contentType
      });
      res.end(content, "utf8", callback(req, res));
    }
  });
});

function callback(req, res) {
  if (req.url == "/" || req.url == "/index") {
    fs.readdir(resDir, (err, files) => {
      files.forEach(file => {
        resDirFiles.push(file);
        res.end("<h1>Ok</h1>"); // placeholder
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try `res.send()` instead of `res.end`?

Comment: I'm trying to not use Express for this

Comment: if you don't want Express, then, like @Neo is saying, you have to use something like `http-server` or `http`

Comment: You're calling `res.end` twice. A request can only have one response. Do you want to send the file content, or your custom HTML response? Also `callback` does not return a function, so passing its return value to `res.end` has no effect.

Comment: Is there a way to send both the file content and a custom HTML response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution makes use of module `http` and it list all files in directory `resDir`. It also provides links to the files, but it doesn't work on all browsers/servers due to security concerns, to avoid giving a free gateway between the user and the server. For something more robust you [should have a file server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http).

```js
var path = require('path')
var http = require('http')
var find = require('find')

var resDir = __dirname

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html')
  find.file(resDir, function (files) {
    res.write('<ul>')
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let fileRelative = path.relative(resDir, files[i])
      res.write('<li><a href="' + fileRelative + '">' + fileRelative + '</a></li>')
    }
    res.write('</ul>')
    res.end()
  })
}).listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('server start at port 3000')
})
```

Now you can access it on `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Eventually I'm trying to list the files in the directory as links on the webpage, the `<h1>Ok</h1>` is just a placeholder. I haven't found a way to implement this yet.

Comment: @JLLKFO how do you want to list the files? In the html page?

Comment: @JLLKFO I changed the code according to your requirements. I used the module [`find`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/find), install it if necessary with `npm i find`. Can you test it? `__dirname` is the current directory where this script is stored but you can chose another one.

Comment: @JLLKFO I tested now on my node environment and it does work. Can you test it?

Comment: I just do not understand what do you mean by "links"

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Your code seems to just list the files. I'm trying to literally have links to any files discovered in the `resources` folder, i.e. if there are two jpgs in there, I'd like to have two links to them from the homepage. But I also have an upload html page, where I can "upload" files into `resources`, after which returning home should list them. Does this make sense?

Comment: @JLLKFO I changed the code to be more precise according to your needs, but it doesn't work on all browsers, due to security concerns (imagine the user having access to server's files). What you want is a file server, and do not expect me to write one from scratch to you :)

Comment: @JLLKFO what you want is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869/1243247

Comment: Ah, I hadn't even considered that. I'll take a look at your link. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can straight away use lot of npm project for this, like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)