# How to run this AJAX JavaScript Coding?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, web

My Source from W3 Schools : https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_ajax_array

When I running this ajax example in w3 source it's running successfully.

When I try to execute the same code in my local its' not running .The code is below.

Is there I need any server for running this example.

ajax.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Use the XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a file.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.name;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

json_demo.txt

```
{
    "name":"John",
    "age":31,
    "pets":[
        { "animal":"dog", "name":"Fido" },
        { "animal":"cat", "name":"Felix" },
        { "animal":"hamster", "name":"Lightning" }
    ]
}
```

How to run this file in my local computer?
Help me to begin my Ajax Learning......

Comment: You cannot read the local file from javascript. It is against the security protocol.

Comment: Yes, you would need a localhost server, e.g. [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: Then how to run this ?

Comment: @AkashShrivastava suggest any sites for xampp with ajax.

Comment: I would suggest instead of using your own file, use a public API to get data (e.g. [public dummy rest api](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/)) here you'll find plenty endpoints from where you can fetch json. Just replace `"json_demo.txt"` in `xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo.txt", true);` with any of those public URLs

Comment: Check error console  of your browser for error in script

Comment: @AkashShrivastava Thanking You,It;s Working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run this example on local machine you should use Web server. You can setup any web-server you want to serve static `txt` file you mentioned.

Here some of them:

- [nginx](https://nginx.org/)
- [apache](https://www.apache.org/)

Because you're studying JS I'd suggest you to use Node.js and create a simple HTTP server. Look at the answers for this question if you're interested in this way: [Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http)