# Enable directory listing in http-server

Tags: npm, httpserver

I've just installed `http-server` via:

```
npm install --global http-server
```

I want to set up a server that will show me my directory listing for testing and learning purposes. I've already experimented with:

> `-d` Show directory listings (defaults to `true`)
>
> `-i` Display autoIndex (defaults to `true`)

But all the time after creating a server it opens index.html instead of directory listing.

This is more or less what I'd like to get instead of opening index.html:

[image: directory listing]

What I would like to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `-i` Display autoIndex (defaults to `true`)

This is what makes `http-server` display the index (enabled by default), you can turn this off like that:

```
http-server -i false
```

Comment: I could swear that I tried this yesterday but only today when I read your comment it works for me, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
npm install http-server -g
cd Directory/
http-server
```

If you don't want to use Http-server follow on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869/9233171)

Comment: Thanks! It's almost what I'm trying to achieve. Now when I run `http-server` I can see my directory folder but when I click on it, it automatically runs `index.html` even though there are some other files as well.