# Node - get file from local file system using http

Tags: node.js, http

I was wondering if its possible to get a file from the local file system (where node is running) using HTTP GET?

Meaning using a package such as axios, or request to get the file

The path to the file is full path.

Comment: You can find details here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Check out this, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http/24575241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check out the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module..

Comment: I'm familiar with fs, but what will happen if the url is an actual web url? I suppose the call to fs will throw an error, no?

Comment: fs is for local file-system. You should perform a string check and make sure the path your passing into fs is valid and not a web url before you attempt to read file system. Either way if the fs fails it will throw an error that you can catch/read.You can use a simple npm lib like https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-url ... If it returns boolean true then dont read the file-system. Or if you dont care then just let fs return the error when it fails to find the file.

Comment: Okay, so this was my implemetation idea. But I wanted to make sure there's no way to avoid the string check

Comment: Read my last comment. You can do a string check against the url before sending the file path into fs