# How do I load my HTML and CSS file with my NODEJS server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am running a nodejs server file, code below. Currently the code you see does not have the HTML or CSS referenced because I don't know how to do it.

```
const http = require('http');

// Create an instance of the http server to handle HTTP requests
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Set a response type of plain text for the response
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // Send back a response and end the connection
    res.end('Hello World!\n');
});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Node server running on port 3000');
```

[In a folder that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k0Hh.png)

I have already searched online for hours, looked at previous stackoverflow posts, and I still haven't found the answer. I got the HTML file to load at one point, but I was not able to get the CSS file to load.

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Tip: Search for the term "static files" for when you want to serve files from the filesystem directly - that way you can expose a directory and its contents without needing to add individual urls for each file you want to serve from that directory (like `*.html` and `*.css` files).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js quick file server (static files over HTTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http)

Answer (score 0):

Html and Css files are static files so you need to search about serving static files with Node.js.

check this tutorial : [How to serve static files](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/)

or this one: [Node.js server without a framework](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework)

Comment: If the HTML file has events in it and scripts in it, like button clicks, will these events still occur even though the files are considered static and not dynamic?

Comment: Indeed. Once your html file is loaded in the client browser, everything works normally.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help. Peace and blessings on you.