# Core Nodejs static file serving

Tags: node.js

How to serve static files with core Nodejs(not using any framework). Also, Indicate a `public` folder as `static` folder like `express` middleware.

```
   express.static(root, [options])
```

In my code, static files are working/serving with local development, but not working/serving some static files like `.css/fonts` over the `https` on deployment.

Comment: Idk what you mean by "core nodejs" but to serve static files in expressjs you need to use this code `app.use(express.static('./public/'))`

Comment: I meant, not using any framework. (Updated the question)

Comment: This can absolutely be done, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server/23122981#23122981). But a framework like Express or Koa will save you a lot of headaches.