# Serving up a node project from within a docker file

Tags: node.js, docker, vite, uppy, tus

I'm pretty new to the node.js/frontend world and am getting bamboozled by the various frameworks.

I have a node project that I can run locally. I've got a simple proof of concept up and running using the [uppy front end](https://uppy.io/) framework, supported by [tus.io](https://tus.io/) to handle backend uploads. I use [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html) to serve everything up locally using `yarn start`.

I'm looking to run it from within a docker file so I can host it and show some colleagues. Can anyone help to get this running, it doesn't have to be pretty.

Things I've tried:

- using a standard HTTP server implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29046869), got errors about `.js` files not `cjs` then getting `Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “@uppy/core” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything` in the browser
- trying to use vite from a docker file but that bombed out with `FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`
- Using webpack, but that was an all round fail with mostly cjs errors.

my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Node.js + Uppy Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>The app requires JavaScript to be enabled.</noscript>
    <button id="modalVisit">Upload To Visit</button>
    <script src="./upload_to_visit.js" type="module"></script>
    <noscript>The app requires JavaScript to be enabled.</noscript>
    <button id="modalDataset">Upload To Dataset</button>
    <script src="./upload_to_dataset.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my `upload_to_visit.js`:

```
import Uppy from '@uppy/core'
import Dashboard from '@uppy/dashboard';
import Tus from '@uppy/tus'
import GoldenRetriever from '@uppy/golden-retriever';

import '@uppy/core/dist/style.css'
import '@uppy/drag-drop/dist/style.min.css';
import '@uppy/dashboard/dist/style.min.css';

const uppy = new Uppy({
    debug: true,
    autoProceed: false,
})

uppy.use(Dashboard, {
    inline: false,
    trigger:"#modalDataset",
    target: 'body',
    note:"to upload to a dataset",
    proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy: false,
    showProgressDetails: true,
    fileManagerSelectionType:"files",
})

uppy.use(Tus, { endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/files/datasets/' });
uppy.use(GoldenRetriever);
```

(I'm aware the the URL will need to change to accommodate the docker network)

my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "node_uppy",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@uppy/core": "^3.3.1",
    "@uppy/drag-drop": "^3.0.2",
    "@uppy/dashboard": "",
    "@uppy/tus": "^3.1.2",
    "@uppy/golden-retriever": "^3.1.0",
    "formidable": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm-run-all --parallel",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:client",
    "start:client": "vite"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in a **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
RUN vite build
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Then run `docker build -t app .`. That should be enough to give you a head-start.

Comment: thanks alot for getting back. I'm getting `ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c vite build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127`. i don't think it cab find `vite`. I've tried running `yarn install`, `yarn build` locally before running the docker build command just incase but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: ahh ok, i added `"buildvite": "vite build",` to the `package.json` and then run `RUN yarn buildvite` from the dockerfile.
However, I still can't figure out which IP (presumably 127.0.0.1) or port to hit the front end on?

Comment: If you're able to build the image successfully (with the status code 0), then you can run a container from that image by running `docker run -p 8080:80 app` command. If the container is at *running* state, you should be able to visit <http://localhost:8080> to access the frontend app.

Comment: Yes it was a port mapping issue. I was doing `8080:8080` instead of `8080:80`. Many thanks for all your help, you're a legend!.

Comment: Glad I was of your help and your problem is resolved now. Take care.